# Компилятор выкидывает ошибку когда я ввожу число типа double. Не могу разобраться что делать

Tags: java, intellij-idea, компилятор

Решаю задачу с `JavaRush`, встретился с такой проблемой - компилятор выкидывает ошибку:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2413)
    at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:11)
```

Я так понимаю что-то с моим `IntelliJ IDEA`, потому-что код программы скопировал с сайта, но ошибку всё равно выкидывает.
При том если я ввожу целое число, например `36` то всё отлично, но если я введу допустим `36.0` то компилятор сразу кидает ошибку.
Кто знает что это может быть?

Полный код программы:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    private static boolean isHigh;
    private static boolean isLow;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double bodyTemperature = scanner.nextDouble();

        isHigh = bodyTemperature > 37;
        isLow = bodyTemperature < 36;

        if (isHigh) {
            System.out.println("температура тела высокая");
        } else if (isLow) {
            System.out.println("температура тела низкая");
        } else {
            System.out.println("температура тела нормальная");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Уверенны что вводите число через точку, а не через запятую?

Comment: @AlekseiGaile да, через точку

Comment: @AlekseiGaile  Скорее всего используется локаль, в которой десятичный разделитель - запятая

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего у Вас используется локаль, в которой десятичный разделитель не точка. Вы можете при инициализации `java.util.Scanner` указать явно локаль:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: Сделал так как вы сказали, всё сработало, спасибо!